# How to make the lower navigation bar show what's the last thing in the activity?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-xml

I was trying to make a lower navigation bar and because the views where a lot I needed to use a scroll view but the problem is that the last element in the scroll view doesn't appear because of the navigation bar.
so what can I do to make last element appear??
my xml code is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#E6E6E6"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".mainPage">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
            android:text="Servings"
            android:textColor="@color/purple_700"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:id="@+id/servings"
            android:hint="Servings that you will eat"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
            android:text="grams per serving"
            android:textColor="@color/purple_700"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:id="@+id/grams"
            android:hint="grams per serving"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
            android:text="calories for each serving"
            android:textColor="@color/purple_700"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:id="@+id/calories"
            android:hint="calories for each serving"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
            android:text="meal name"
            android:textColor="@color/purple_700"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:hint="type the meal name"/>
    </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/add"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
                android:text="Add"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dont"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
                android:text="Don’t know how many calories are in this meal ?"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/main_food"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
                android:text="What have you eaten today"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/adding_food"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
                android:text="Food Adding"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/profile_food"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
                android:text="Profile"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

so how can I make the last element in the scroll view because the navigaion bar is blocking it (it's in the front of it so the last element doesn't show.
[This is an image of it and as you can see the navigation bar is in the front of the last element so it doesn't show because of that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3KPI.png)

Comment: in your scrollview set bottom margin/padding greater than or equal to the height of bottom navigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `id` to Bottom navigation bar `LinearLayout`

Add `android:layout_above="@+id/yourbottomlayoutid"` , `android:layout_height="match_parent"` and `android:fillViewport="true"` to your `ScrollView`.

For reference check below code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#E6E6E6"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".mainPage">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/llBottomBar">
       <!--Your LinearLayout-->
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llBottomBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <!--Bottom navigation bar buttons-->
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:paddingBottom = "Xdp"`, where `X` is something bigger than your bottom bar, to the last LinearLayout.

Example: `android:paddingBottom = "30dp"`